# How to change the y in flexdashboard selectInput

Tags: r, reactive, flexdashboard, selectinput

I'm trying to make a flexdashboard using IMDb data, that has an interactive jitter plot where you can change the x and y for visualizing hierarchical clustering result. The code that I've already made can change only the x and number of k. I think I should use `reactive` function but I don't really understand in using that. I've already tried many other ways from youtube and some documentary but still can't change the y. Here is [layout of my dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkaGy.png), The y stuck at the runtime variable

```
data=df %>% 
  select(Rating, Votes, Gross, Runtime, Metascore)

selectInput("x", label = "X : ",choices = names(data))

selectInput("y", label = "Y : ",choices = names(data))

sliderInput('k',"Cluster",min = 2,max = 10, value = 6)

selectedData=reactive({
  data %>% select(input$x, input$y)
})

data_scaled=scale(data)

dist_data=dist(data_scaled, method='euclidean')

hc_data=hclust(dist_data, method = "average")

renderPlot({
  ggplot(selectedData(),
         aes(x=!!rlang::sym(input$x), y=!!rlang::sym(input$y),
             col=factor(cutree(hc_data, k=input$k))))+
    geom_jitter(size=5, alpha=0.5 )+
    labs(col="Cluster")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative example that seems to work, using the `diamonds` dataset from `ggplot2`. My guess is that the scaling and clustering steps take so long to run that the the y reactive only appears not to work. I would suggest pre-processing your data if app run times are a problem.

```
data=diamonds[1:1e3,] %>% 
    dplyr::select(where(is.numeric))

selectInput("x", label = "X : ",choices = names(data))

selectInput("y", label = "Y : ",choices = names(data))

sliderInput('k',"Cluster",min = 2,max = 10, value = 6)

data_scaled=scale(data)

dist_data=dist(data_scaled, method='euclidean')

hc_data=hclust(dist_data, method = "average")

renderPlot({
    ggplot(data,
           aes(x=!!rlang::sym(input$x), y=!!rlang::sym(input$y),
               col=factor(cutree(hc_data, k=input$k))))+
        geom_jitter(size=5, alpha=0.5 )+
        labs(col="Cluster")
})
```